# ffmpeg will not reconnect to stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've seen a few questions about this, most seem to offer the same answer, but none of them work for me.

I want to monitor an live audio stream (for silences) using ffmpeg and am doing so with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_delay_max 300 -i http://mystream:port -af silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=5 -f null -
```

If I turn off the server, I get this:

```
[http @ 0x7fcba3407cc0] Stream ends prematurely at 196076, should be 18446744073709551615
http://mystream:port: Input/output error
size=N/A time=00:00:12.25 bitrate=N/A speed=3.01x    
video:0kB audio:2110kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

I was expecting ffmpeg to sit there and wait and reconnect back up when I restart the server, but it just crashes out with the above error.

I've tried a number of combinations of the command above, but every time it just stops.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.